# Syncfusion JavaScript (ES5) Export Chart with Custom Font Family

Tags: javascript, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I have a custom font from google fonts. This font family, defined everywhere in the chart.

*titleStyle.fontFamily, subTitleStyle.fontFamily, primaryXAxis.titleStyle.fontFamily etc.*

I am exporting the chart like this:
`chart.export('PNG','filename');`

But the chart did not exported with my custom font.

I am looking for an in-build functionality to define the font family of the chart once, or exporting the chart with a custom font family.

Thank you.

***PS***: Canvas rendering, is not a solution for my problem. I need the same export functionality for ***AccumulationChart*** too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have specified different font family for chart title, subtitle and primary x axis title. We were able to export chart with mentioned font family. We have attached the sample and exported image for your reference.

**Sample :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/udq6wm

**Screenshot :**

[image: Export Chart]